Beamer: separate counters for theorems and continuing counters
I am using Continuing example Counters in Beamer
to get a single example that can span several frames in Beamer and Beamer: Grouping environment counters to separate theorem-like counters. But now the MWE below raises the following warnings (TeXLive 2024, beamer 2024/01/06 v3.71):

LaTeX Warning: Command `\thelemma' already defined -- not changed on input line 8.


LaTeX Warning: Command `\theexample' already defined -- not changed on input line 10.

Pretty sure it was working fine in TeXLive 2023. Any idea?
MWE:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\undef{\lemma}
\undef{\example}
\undef{\definition}
\newtheorem{lemma}{\translate{Lemma}}
\theoremstyle{example}
\newtheorem{example}{\translate{Example}}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{\translate{Definition}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{lemma}{Foobar}
Foo and bar.
\end{lemma}
\begin{lemma}{Barfoo}
Either bar or foo.
\end{lemma}
\begin{theorem}{Something new}
No, not really.
\end{theorem}
\begin{example}{Color?}
Indeed.
\end{example}
\begin{definition}
A definition.   
\end{definition}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


You can avoid the warning by undefining these macros, too:
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\undef{\lemma}
\undef{\example}
\undef{\definition}
\undef{\thelemma}
\undef{\theexample}
\undef{\thedefinition}
\newtheorem{lemma}{\translate{Lemma}}
\theoremstyle{example}
\newtheorem{example}{\translate{Example}}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{\translate{Definition}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{lemma}{Foobar}
Foo and bar.
\end{lemma}
\begin{lemma}{Barfoo}
Either bar or foo.
\end{lemma}
\begin{theorem}{Something new}
No, not really.
\end{theorem}
\begin{example}{Color?}
Indeed.
\end{example}
\begin{definition}
A definition.   
\end{definition}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


